# How to stop a jQuery effect on a menu item with the class of .curent?

Tags: jquery, function, jquery-animate

I have a list of blog categories in a sidebar to the right of my page.

I have set-up a jQuery effect so that when you hover over a category name it animates with 5px padding to the left.

Everything is working well, but if you click on a category, I want it to bring you to that category page with the same category sidebar list, but with the current category having a class of .current.

I would like the current category to already have the 5px padding to the left and have no effect when hovered over.

Basically just to make it stand out from the other categories in the list.

Here is the jQuery I have atm:

```
// blog categories animation
$(function() {
    $('#blog-categories ul li a').hover(
    function(){ $(this).find('img').animate({paddingLeft: '+=5'}, 100); },
    function(){ $(this).find('img').animate({paddingLeft: '-=5'}, 100); }
    );
});
```

If anybody knows a good way to have the 5px added padding already present on the current category item.

ie '#blog-categories ul li a.current'

and have no further animation when hovered over, that would be great!

I hope I have explained myself ok here :)

---

Here's a screenshot of what I would like on the .current category item:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method

```
$(function() {
    $('#blog-categories ul li a').hover(
    function(){ $(this).not('.current').find('img').animate({paddingLeft: '+=5'}, 100); },
    function(){ $(this).not('.current').find('img').animate({paddingLeft: '-=5'}, 100); }
    );
});
```

To have the 5px padding present, why not simply add it to the `.current` class?

Comment: Cheers I'll try this just now and let you know how I get on :)

Comment: Worked a treat! Thanks for the quick response :)